# web crawler out of bound parsing

Tags: html, string

I have the two following methods,

```
public void connect (String website) throws IOException {
    URL u = new URL(website);
    URLConnection conn = u.openConnection();
```

Comment: why dont you use regex to find links? :S or html parser library [which is infact regex nyway]